# Google Calender event alert app 

Tags: software-recommendation, google-calendar, google

I'd like to be alerted before my Google calender appointment's are due, and I don't want to install a ton of dependencies, I have limited space.

Any suggestions?

I tried one but it polled Google too much and it broke, I forgot which it is though.

Answer (score 1):

Evolution? It's primarily an email client, I know but it does also have an events/calendar side to it that can sync in with Google. It's also included in the default install of Ubuntu.

No idea if it'll automatically create reminders. I'm sure there's something you could hack together (a little script that talked to Evolution) if it doesn't do it all for you.

Comment: I don't want to install a ton of dependencies, I have limited space. Thanks though.

Comment: As I say, if you're using a standard install of Ubuntu, it's already there. Nothing extra to install.

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu and have removed most things about 100 MB or larger, not sure how big Evolution is. I have limited space and one big thing that attracts me to Linux is that it can be minimalist and extremely customisable. I'm sure there is a great script or app someone has made already.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but you might be looking for something like [gcalcli](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli).  You might also want to see [this fork](https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/gcalcli/overview) for some modifications which allow it to be used in a daemon mode, and provide pop-up snooze-able reminders.